# revive adserver delivery scripts functlionality

Tags: openx

Where can I find some docs or article where is short description of scripts at www/delivery/ folder of revive adserver

I have such lists at www/delivery/

```
./lg.php
./ag.php
./fl.js
./spcjs.php
./tv.php
./dxmlrpc.php
./ax.php
./ck.php
./fc.php
./ai.php
./afr.php
./tjs.php
./avw.php
./ac.php
./al.php
./alocal.php
./spc.php
./axmlrpc.php
./crossdomain.xml
./ti.php
./ajs.php
./ajs_test.php
./apu.php
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No document available to explain the coding of all delivery files. You can understand which file will be used for which functionality from this screen image : 
[image: Delivery File Use In Revive Adserver]

Comment: thanks man, that's a great help right there, If we could all share their work product on revive then we could have a proper documentation.  I am collecting all information available and I will also share a compilation of KBs on revive adserver as soon as it's ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this in the admin panel at /adserver/www/admin/account-settings-banner-delivery.php